# JDK version (Java Development Kit update)

Tags: java, version

what is the last version of JDK with netbeans?

Comment: Where have you looked? Please give some indication that you've at least tried.

Comment: skaffman, StackOverflow apparently is considered better than Google.  Not bad.

Answer (score 1):

JDK 6 update 21 is packaged with the latest version of NetBeans (v6.9.1). You can download them both from Oracle's web site [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html).